# Assigning numeric values based on the letters in a string in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that is a single column with 235,886 rows. Each row corresponds to a single word of the English language.

E.g.

```
> words[10000:10005,1]
```

[1] anticontagionist    anticontagious      anticonventional    anticonventionalism anticonvulsive
[6] anticor

What I'd like to do is convert each row to a number based on the letters in it. So, if "a" = 1, "b" = 2, "c" = 3, and "d" = 4, then "abcd" = 10. Does anyone know of a way to do that?

My ultimate goal is to have a function that scans the data.frame for a given numeric value and returns all the strings, i.e. words, with that value. So, continuing from the example above, if I asked for the value 9, this function would return "dad" and any other rows having a numeric value of 9.

Comment: Like `sum(match(strsplit(x, "")[[1]], letters))`?

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a combination of `strsplit` and `match`. I've thrown a `tolower` in there to make sure that we are matching to the right thing.

Here's a function that implements those steps:

```
word_value <- function(words) {
  temp <- strsplit(tolower(words), "", TRUE)
  vapply(temp, function(x) sum(match(x, letters)), integer(1L))
}
```

Here's a sample vector:

```
myvec <- c("and", "dad", "cat", "fox", "mom", "add", "dan")
```

Test it out:

```
word_value(myvec)
# [1] 19  9 24 45 41  9 19

myvec[word_value(myvec) == 9]
# [1] "dad" "add"

myvec[word_value(myvec) > 20]
# [1] "cat" "fox" "mom"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `utf8ToInt`.

```
#using the sample data from Ananda's answer
offset <- utf8ToInt("a") - 1
d <- vapply(tolower(myvec), 
  function(ii) sum(utf8ToInt(ii) - offset), FUN.VALUE = double(1L))
#and dad cat fox mom add dan 
# 19   9  24  45  41   9  19

d[d > 20]
#cat fox mom 
# 24  45  41
```

Using the offset is necessary because `utf8ToInt("a")` is 97, but you want "a" to be 1.

Wrapping with `stack` will give a different format for the output, if preferred:

```
d <- stack(vapply(tolower(myvec), 
  function(ii) sum(utf8ToInt(ii) - offset), FUN.VALUE = double(1L)))
#  values ind
#1     19 and
#2      9 dad
#3     24 cat
#4     45 fox
#5     41 mom
#6      9 add
#7     19 dan

d[d$values > 20,]
#  values ind
#3     24 cat
#4     45 fox
#5     41 mom
```

Comment: Nice. Two suggestions: move the `utf8ToInt("a") + 1` outside of the inner function to `sapply` and change `sapply` to `vapply`. +1

Comment: You're calculating `utf8ToInt("a") + 1` for each word, which seems unnecessary. You can either add it as a fixed value in your `vapply` or calculate it just once. See [here](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/e8f703f11e9d8764b443) for an example.

Comment: I wonder how this function should change if we are dealing with words that may have punctuation. Like `"self-esteem"`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto good question!  I have two quick ideas that I haven't tested or thought about thoroughly.  One would be using something like `chartr` to turn unwanted characters into `"\`"`, which would be 0 with the offset, and the other would be to use subsetting (i.e. something like `sum(utf8ToInt(ii)[utf8ToInt(ii) > 96] - offset)`). I will think about it, but gotta head to bed for now.

Comment: I was just thinking `gsub`bing out the unnecessary stuff. It would give us the same results as if we had used `match(..., nomatch = 0L)`.

Comment: Added to [my SOfun package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun). Hope you don't mind. If you want me to change anything [in the documentation](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/man/word_value.Rd), let me know.